# RavenDB: Why do I get null-values for fields in this multi-map/reduce index?

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

Inspired by Ayende's article https://ayende.com/blog/89089/ravendb-multi-maps-reduce-indexes, I have the following index, that works as such:

```cs
public class Posts_WithViewCountByUser : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<Posts_WithViewCountByUser.Result>
{
    public Posts_WithViewCountByUser()
    {
        AddMap<Post>(posts => from p in posts
            select new
            {
                ViewedByUserId = (string) null,
                ViewCount = 0,

                Id = p.Id,
                PostTitle = p.PostTitle,
            });

        AddMap<PostView>(postViews => from postView in postViews
            select new
            {
                ViewedByUserId = postView.ViewedByUserId,
                ViewCount = 1,

                Id = (string) postView.PostId,
                PostTitle = (string) null,
            });

        Reduce = results => from result in results
            group result by new
            {
                result.Id,
                result.ViewedByUserId
            }
            into g
            select new Result
            {
                ViewCount = g.Sum(x => x.ViewCount),
                Id = g.Key.Id,
                ViewedByUserId = g.Key.ViewedByUserId,
                PostTitle = g.Select(x => x.PostTitle).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
            };

        Store(x => x.PostTitle, FieldStorage.Yes);
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ViewedByUserId { get; set; }
        public int ViewCount { get; set; }
        public string PostTitle { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to query this index like this:

Return all posts including - for a given user - the integer of how many times, the user has viewed the post. The "views" are stored in a separate document type, `PostView`. Note, that my real document types have been renamed here to match the example from the article (I certainly would not implement "most-viewed" this way).

The result from the query I get is correct - i.e. I always get all the `Post` documents with the correct view-count for the user. But my problem is, the *PostTitle* field always is null in the result set (all `Post` documents have a non-null value in the dataset).

I'm grouping by the combination of *userId* and (post)*Id* as my "uniqueness". The way I understand it (and please correct me if I'm wrong), is, that at this point in the reduce, I have a bunch of pseudo-documents with identical *userId* /*postId* combination, some of which come from the `Post` map, others from the `PostView` map. Now I simply find any single pseudo-document of the ones, that actually have a value for *PostTitle* - i.e. one that originates from the `Post` map. These should all obviously have the same value, as it's the same post, just "outer-joined". The `.Select(....).Where(....).FirstOrDefault()` chain is taken from the very example I used as a base. I then set this *ViewCount* value for my final document, which I project into the Result.

My question is: **how do I get the non-null value for the *PostTitle* field in the results?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have:

```
       ViewedByUserId = (string) null,
```

And:

```
        group result by new
        {
            result.Id,
            result.ViewedByUserId
        }
        into g
```

In other words, you are actually grouping by null, which I'm assuming that isn't your intent.

It would be much simpler to have a map/reduce index just on `PostView` and get the `PostTitle` from an include or via a transformer.

You understanding of what is going on is correct, in the sense that you are creating index results with `userId / postId` on them.

Buit what you are *actually* doing is creating results from `PostView` with `userId /postId` and from `Post` with `null /postId`.

And that is why you don't have the matches that you want.

Answer (score 3):

The grouping in the index is incorrect. With the following sample data:

```
new Post { Id = "Post-1", PostTitle = "Post Title", AuthorId = "Author-1" }
new PostView { ViewedByUserId = "User-1", PostId = "Post-1" }
new PostView { ViewedByUserId = "User-1", PostId = "Post-1" }
new PostView { ViewedByUserId = "User-2", PostId = "Post-1" }
```

The index results are like this:

```
ViewCount | Id     | ViewedByUserId | PostTitle
--------- | ------ | -------------- | ----------
 0        | Post-1 | null           | Post Title
 2        | Post-1 | User-1         | null
 1        | Post-1 | User-2         | null
```

The map operation in the index simply creates a common document for all source documents. Thus, the `Post-1` document produces one row, the two documents for `Post-1` and `User-1` produce two rows (which are later reduced to the single row with `ViewCount` == 2) and the document for `Post-1` and `User-2` produces the last row.

The reduce operation the groups all the mapped rows and produces the resulting documents in the index. In this case, the `Post`-sourced document is stored separately from the `PostView`-sourced documents because the `null` value in the `ViewedByUserId` is not grouped with any document from the `PostView` collection.

If you can change your way of storing data, you can solve this issue by storing the number of views directly in the PostView. It would greatly reduce duplicate data in your database while having almost the same cost when updating the view count.

Complete test (needs xunit and RavenDB.Tests.Helpers nugets):

```
using Raven.Abstractions.Indexing;
using Raven.Client;
using Raven.Client.Indexes;
using Raven.Tests.Helpers;
using System.Linq;
using Xunit;

namespace SO41559770Answer
{
    public class SO41559770 : RavenTestBase
    {
        [Fact]
        public void SO41559770Test()
        {
            using (var server = GetNewServer())
            using (var store = NewRemoteDocumentStore(ravenDbServer: server))
            {
                new PostViewsIndex().Execute(store);

                using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
                {
                    session.Store(new Post { Id = "Post-1", PostTitle = "Post Title", AuthorId = "Author-1" });
                    session.Store(new PostView { Id = "Views-1-1", ViewedByUserId = "User-1", PostId = "Post-1", ViewCount = 2 });
                    session.Store(new PostView { Id = "Views-1-2", ViewedByUserId = "User-2", PostId = "Post-1", ViewCount = 1 });
                    session.SaveChanges();
                }

                WaitForAllRequestsToComplete(server);
                WaitForIndexing(store);

                using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
                {
                    var resultsForId1 = session
                        .Query<PostViewsIndex.Result, PostViewsIndex>()
                        .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<PostViewsIndex.Result>()
                        .Where(x => x.PostId == "Post-1" && x.UserId == "User-1");
                    Assert.Equal(2, resultsForId1.First().ViewCount);
                    Assert.Equal("Post Title", resultsForId1.First().PostTitle);
                    var resultsForId2 = session
                        .Query<PostViewsIndex.Result, PostViewsIndex>()
                        .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<PostViewsIndex.Result>()
                        .Where(x => x.PostId == "Post-1" && x.UserId == "User-2");
                    Assert.Equal(1, resultsForId2.First().ViewCount);
                    Assert.Equal("Post Title", resultsForId2.First().PostTitle);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class PostViewsIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<PostView, PostViewsIndex.Result>
    {
        public PostViewsIndex()
        {
            Map = postViews => from postView in postViews
                               let post = LoadDocument<Post>(postView.PostId)
                               select new
                               {
                                   Id = postView.Id,
                                   PostId = post.Id,
                                   PostTitle = post.PostTitle,
                                   UserId = postView.ViewedByUserId,
                                   ViewCount = postView.ViewCount,
                               };
            StoreAllFields(FieldStorage.Yes);
        }


        public class Result
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string PostId { get; set; }
            public string PostTitle { get; set; }
            public string UserId { get; set; }
            public int ViewCount { get; set; }
        }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string PostTitle { get; set; }
        public string AuthorId { get; set; }
    }

    public class PostView
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ViewedByUserId { get; set; }
        public string PostId { get; set; }
        public int ViewCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```